# Discord Bot doesn't send randomly chosen message

Tags: discord.js

I have the following code:

```js
bot.on('message', msg =>{
    if(msg.content === "Hello"){
        const hello1 = 'Hello mah boi! or girl... eh'
        const hello2 = 'Sup.'
        const hello3 = 'Wassup?'
        const hello4 = 'HEEEEEELLLLOOOOO BOOOOOIII'
        const hello5 = 'Are you sure you wanna say hi??'
        const hello6 = '.'
        const hello7 = 'Heeeeeyyyyyyyyy ey eyyyyyyyy'
        
        const items = [
            hello1,
            hello2,
            hello3,
            hello4,
            hello5,
            hello6,
            hello7
        ];
        const rndString = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
        msg.channel.send(rndString);
    }
})
```

I'm trying to make a random message command, but it isn't working. No message is ever sent. It doesn't throw any errors either.

Comment: Are you sure your logic is ever triggered? The "Hello" for instance is case sensitive. There is nothing wrong with your code in that sense.

Comment: Idk man, it's not working

Comment: Can you put in the effort to debug your code? Log  values throughout your code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do the same thing, except with memes. You could try this, this is my code:

```
 const memes = [
 'https://tenor.com/LxdC.gif',
 'https://tenor.com/Fm1D.gif',
 'https://tenor.com/bqltH.gif',
 'https://tenor.com/4nHj.gif',
 'https://tenor.com/zFEB.gif',
 'https://tenor.com/xa3U.gif',
 'https://tenor.com/wMSx.gif',
 'https://tenor.com/HxIT.gif',
 'https://tenor.com/XGES.gif',
 'https://tenor.com/bdnvi.gif',
 'https://tenor.com/yf4L.gif',
 'https://tenor.com/bnU5s.gif',
 'https://tenor.com/xjhw.gif',
 'https://tenor.com/2Rbt.gif',
 'https://tenor.com/bE4YO.gif',
 'https://tenor.com/bEOYD.gif'
 ]
 client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.content.startsWith('!memes')) {
 const response = memes[Math.floor(Math.random() * memes.length)];
 message.channel.send(response);
 }
 });
 client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.content.startsWith('!memesdm')) {
 const response = memes[Math.floor(Math.random() * memes.length)];
 message.author.send(response);
 }
 });
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do it like this:

```
bot.on('message', msg =>{
    if(msg.content === "Hello"){
    

function random() {
    
    const hello1 = 'Hello mah boi! or girl... eh'
            const hello2 = 'Sup.'
            const hello3 = 'Wassup?'
            const hello4 = 'HEEEEEELLLLOOOOO BOOOOOIII'
            const hello5 = 'Are you sure you wanna say hi??'
            const hello6 = '.'
            const hello7 = 'Heeeeeyyyyyyyyy ey eyyyyyyyy'
    
        var rand = [hello1, hello2, hello3, hello4, hello5, hello6, hello7];
    
        return rand[Math.floor(Math.random()*rand.length)];
      }
message.channel.send(random())
   }
})
```

Comment: Ok Imma try :D.

Comment: Still not working... Idk whats happening!!

Comment: In this block you pass in the message object as `msg`, yet use `message.channel.send()`???